# How can I successfully boot my Ubuntu Live USB?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I have an Acer Predator  G9-593-7757 15,6"/i7-7700/32 GB RAM/512 GB SSD/1 TB HDD/GTX1070 with currently Windows 10 installed and would like to install Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 16.10 on it.

In order to do this I have made a few attempts to create Live USB's using [RUFUS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), a [Mac with DD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac) and [WIN32 DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/). In all three cases the USB is detected as containing an Ubuntu partition and opens the Ubuntu start screen (Ubuntu logo with 5 dots). At this point it hangs for about a minute and then after showing the following error, busybox opens.

```
apci mst0101:00: plaatofrm device creationed failed -16
noveau 0000:01:00:0: priv: hubo: 00d054 00000007 (18408216)
nouveau 0000:01:00:0 DRM: failed to create kernal channel
```

I use a 60 GB SanDisk for the Live USB. 
Pressing the arrow key while waiting for Ubuntu to load gives me the error `/dev/sr0: no medium found`. How can I successfully boot the USB media?

Doing nouveau.modeset=0 as suggested @cl-netbox results in some addition

doing this causes the error

```
platfirn NSTF0101:00: failed to claim resource 1
ACPI MST0101:00: platform device creationed failed -16  
 usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64 error 
-110 follow by error usb 1-2: device descriptor
usb 1-2: device nto accepting address 4 error -62
usb 1-2: device nto accepting address 5 error -62
```

So here is a picture of one set of parameters I tried 
[image: boot settings]
and their results
[image: results nouveau.nomodeset=0a]

This is probably the most hopeful configuration I tried so far

Edit: using a dvd rather then usb I was able to get the system to boot but the mouse does not work(both touchpad and external mouse), keyboard does work though.

Comment: Anything I can add for more detailed information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have very new graphics hardware, which is known to have compatibility issues with the open source `nouveau` drivers, especially when it comes to the NVIDIA GTX 10xx GPU adapter series.

Boot the Ubuntu installation media you have created and select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
(Note : Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`)
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu Live desktop and start the installation of Ubuntu.

After the installation has finished, boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as the default system to boot.
Add the same parameter again when booting the freshly installed Ubuntu system for the first time.
Now, before doing something else ... install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers from a virtual console.

When the login screen appears press : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-375 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Additional information : Do not forget to disable Fast startup and Hibernation in Windows.
In case that the USB still doesn't boot properly, use the parameter `nomodeset` instead of `nouveau.modeset=0`. If this also does not work : create a new and properly booting USB installation media as explained in chat and described in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758658/creating-a-usb-media-using-unetbootin-isnt-recognized-as-booting-media/758660#758660) to an earlier question.

If none of the boot parameter options provided in the comments below work - alternatively
burn the ISO file to a DVD and boot from this media to install the Ubuntu operating system.

Regarding the error message in the screenshot `can’ t open /dev/sr0: no medium found` ...
The kernel does not recognize or can not find a DVD. When you burn the ISO file to a DVD and boot from the DVD installation media, the error message most probably will not appear anymore.

Comment: doing this causes the error usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64 error -110 follow by error usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64 error -71 (more in question)

Comment: By the way after the last character is after the --- right?

Comment: @Thijser Boot into BIOS and check whether you can disable NVIDIA Optimus, this is possible in many new machines. If yes, disable it until the system and the NVIDIA drivers are installed. Also try whether it works when you remove the two signs (--) before adding the boot parameter at the end of the linux line ! :)

Comment: Cannot find the BIOS option.

Comment: @Thijser Try to boot with one of the following parameters (use one parameter only at the same time) -> acpi=off | noacpi | pci=noacpi | acpi=noirq | noapic | nolapic ! :)

Comment: Should I keep removing the --- and keep the quietsplash? What about the nomodeset (which at least shows me what is happening)

Comment: Hmm pci=noacpi causes a black screen rather then the ubuntu loading screen and doesn't give any errors (but doesn't appear to do anything either). Something to take note off

Comment: The final answer was using the DVD.